# window.addEventListener doesn't update state as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build infinity scroll from scratch.Here is code:

```
import React,{useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';

const Container:React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
  const [ scrollNumber, setScrollNumber ] = useState<number>(1);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<any[]>([]);
 useEffect(() => {
  async function main(){
      const req = await  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      const result = await req.json();
      const pst = result.splice(0,10*scrollNumber);
      setPosts(pst)

    function scrollHandler(){
   if(containerRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect().bottom === window.innerHeight){
          console.log("Salam", scrollNumber);
          setScrollNumber(scrollNumber + 1);
        }
  }
  window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
  }
  main()
},[])
 useEffect(() => {
  const loadData = async () => {
    const req = await  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    const result = await req.json();
    const pst = result.splice(0,10*scrollNumber);
    setPosts(pst)
  }
  loadData()
 },[scrollNumber])
  return (
    <div  ref={containerRef}>
      {posts.map(post => (
        <div key={post.id}>
          <br/>
          <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      (<p>{post.body}</p>)
      <code>{post.userId}</code>
      <br/><br/>
      <hr/>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}


export default Container
```

But there is a problem. When I test it. it always updates to 2 nothing else. I searched for it. I found that window.addEventListener remembers only initialState that's why state always updates to 2. But I couldn't find any code solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the first `useEffect` the dependency array is empty, which mean if you use any state variable inside it, the value of it not gonna change inside the effect

As I see you are using `scrollNumber` to set the next state of `setScrollNumber(scrollNumber + 1);` and value of `scrollNumber` is not gonna change inside effect because of the dependency array is empty

So you have to tell the react to reinitialize the effect if you have any changes to the `scrollNumber`

so put `scrollNumber` as an dependency will work for you

```
 useEffect(() => {
     ...

    function scrollHandler(){
        if(containerRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect().bottom === window.innerHeight) {
            console.log("Salam", scrollNumber);
            setScrollNumber(scrollNumber + 1);
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);

.....
}, [scrollNumber]) //add a dependency
```

Comment: when I add scrollNumber as dependency it starts to repeat fetching multiple times

Comment: It should because you have put `scrollNumber` as an dependency to the second useEffect so when `scrollNumber` get change effect will call and fetch happens, if you dont need that remove it from dependancy array of second useEffect

Comment: np, glad to helpyou